# Get Json key from array

Tags: php, json

So I have a bit of JSON which looks like this:

```
{  
    "workshops":[  
        {  
            "workshop1":{  
                "id":1
            }
        },
        {  
            "workshop2":{  
                "id":2
            }
        },
        {  
            "workshop3":{  
                "id":3
            }
        },
        {  
            "workshop4":{  
                "id":4
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What I would like to do is get **workshop3** without using indexing, so I can't do

$json["workshops"][2]["workshop3"]

So my question how can I get workshop3? I can redesign the Json file if necessary.

Comment: Can't you just loop over $json["workshops"] and check if the current item is "workshop3"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make your json string  such a way :

```
{"workshops":{
      "workshop1":{"id":1},
      "workshop2":{"id":2},
      "workshop3":{"id":3}}}
```

Then you can avoid indexes

```
$json = json_decode($str, true);
var_dump( $json["workshops"]["workshop3"]);
```

result:

```
array(1) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(3)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Without redesign JSON, you may use function `array_keys($json['workshops'])`, which returns array of keys, ex.:

```
$keys = ['workshops1', 'workshops2', 'workshops3'];
$keyName = $keys[2]; 
$workhopValue = $json['workshops'][$keyName];
```

But it is bad workaround, IMHO.

Comment: Without redesign JSON `$workhopValue = $json['workshops'][$keyName];` does not work. Only `$json['workshops'][2][$keyName];` when `keyname` is  `workshops2`